# How to calculate the time Complexity big O of this code in Detail?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, time-complexity, big-o

I have tried to analyse what the time complexity of this code will be, but I am stuck. Do I consider it to be O(n^2) time complexity because of the two for loops, or is it just O(n) because the second for loop isn't always run?
With this code, I have to scan a 2d array based on a graph

```
//adj is edgeMatrix
public int[] getClosenessCentrality(int[][] adj){
    int size = adj.length * adj.length;
    int[] closeness = new int[size];
    for (int vertex = 0; vertex < adj.length; vertex++) {
        boolean[] visited = new boolean[size];
        PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(size);


        pq.add(vertex);


        while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
            int u = pq.remove();
            if(!visited[u]) {
                visited[u] = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    //Priority Queue speeds up extract-min
                    if (!visited[i]) {
                        if (adj[u][i] > 0) {
                            pq.add(adj[u][i]+1);
                        } 

                    }
                }
                closeness[vertex] += 1;
            }

        }
    }

    return closeness;
}
```

Comment: Because of 2 loops,  I think complexity will be (items in first loop)*(items in 2nd loop) ie . (adj.length*size)

Comment: above was the wrost case scenario in best case it can be O(n) ie. linear

Comment: Accessing `adj[u][i]` seems to often result in an  `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because the `adj[u]` array is of length `adj[u].length`, but `i` can be as high as `adj.length * adj.length`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `n = adj.length` the complexity is `O(n^3 log(n))`.

Here is why.

1. For `n` different values of `vertex` we:
2. For all `n^2` possible edges we:
3. Add to the priority queue, and remove from the priority queue.  (Which are all `O(log(n^2)) = O(2 log(n)) = O(log(n))` operations.)

So put that together and we have `O(n^3)` possible operations of complexity `O(log(n))` for a `O(n^3 log(n))` total.